# Customize NSToolbar - Disable "Use small size"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, customization, nstoolbar

How do I disable the "Use small size" option in the toolbar? I am using Xcode 4.

(That's the option that appears when users go to customize the Toolbar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `NSToolbar`, override `-setSizeMode:` and in your implementation call `[super setSizeMode: NSToolbarSizeModeRegular];`.

If you're instantiating the toolbar in Interface Builder then make sure you assign your subclass to the toolbar in the nib.

```
@implementation RKToolbar
- (void)setSizeMode:(NSToolbarSizeMode)aSizeMode
{
    [super setSizeMode:NSToolbarSizeModeRegular];
}
@end
```

This won't remove the checkbox from the customize panel but it will prevent it from doing anything.

There's not really a supported way to remove the checkbox. This does work but it's pretty hacky:

```
//in your NSToolbar subclass
- (void)runCustomizationPalette:(id)sender
{
    [super runCustomizationPalette:sender];

    NSWindow* toolbarWindow = [NSApp mainWindow];

    NSWindow* sheet = [toolbarWindow attachedSheet];

    for(NSView* view in [[sheet contentView] subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]])
        {
            if([[[(NSButton*)view cell] valueForKey:@"buttonType"] integerValue] == NSSwitchButton)
            {
                [view setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! (it _would_ be nice to hide the box altogether...)

Comment: ps. i went to File > Open Quickly... to see which class defines the "Use small size" box, but I don't see it under NSToolbar.h. Where is it done?

Comment: I added some code to hide the checkbox. It's not perfect (the checkbox is initially visible but it disappears once the sheet is open) but it does work.

Comment: Wouldn't you still be able to switch to small size by right-clicking on the toolbar? I'd like to make a toolbar like XCode has, where you can choose between text, icon and both, but the other choices are hidden...

Answer (score 5):

If you're not distributing on the Mac App Store, and don't mind subclassing private methods, you can create an `NSToolbarSubclass` and override `_allowsSizeMode:` to return `NO`:

```
- (BOOL)_allowsSizeMode:(NSToolbarSizeMode)mode {
    return mode != NSToolbarSizeModeSmall;
}
```

This has the added benefit of removing the checkbox from the customization sheet, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rob Keniger for the excellent start. If you can have your custom toolbar as a delegate of your window, you can avoid having "Use small size" visible by getting at the sheet before it is displayed on screen. Do this by implementing [NSToolbar window:willPositionSheet:usingRect:] in the custom toolbar class. Elsewhere in your code, you'll need to do:

```
[myWindowWithToolbar setDelegate:myInstanceOfXXToolbar];
```

Here's the updated custom toolbar class:

```
@implementation XXToolbar

- (void)setSizeMode:(NSToolbarSizeMode)aSizeMode
{
    [super setSizeMode:NSToolbarSizeModeRegular];
}

- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSView *buttonView = nil;

    for(NSView* view in [[sheet contentView] subviews])
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]])
        {
            if([[[(NSButton*)view cell] valueForKey:@"buttonType"] integerValue] == NSSwitchButton)
            {
                buttonView = view;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (buttonView) {
        [buttonView setHidden:YES];

        // This is important as it causes the sheet to redraw without the button off screen
        [[sheet contentView] display];
    }

    return rect;
}

@end
```

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 2.2 version of @MacGreg's solution. You can keep your `NSWindowDelegate` wherever you like, just ensure at least the following is called:

```
var toolbar: UniformToolbar!

func window(window: NSWindow, willPositionSheet sheet: NSWindow, usingRect rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {

    toolbar.removeSizeToggle(window: sheet)

    return rect
}
```

### Toolbar Subclass without the Checkbox

```
class UniformToolbar: NSToolbar {

    override var sizeMode: NSToolbarSizeMode {
        get {
            return NSToolbarSizeMode.Regular
        }
        set { /* no op */ }
    }

    func removeSizeToggle(window window: NSWindow) {

        guard let views = window.contentView?.subviews else { return }

        let toggle: NSButton? = views.lazy
            .flatMap({ (view: NSView) -> NSButton? in view as? NSButton })
            .filter({ (button: NSButton) -> Bool in

                guard let buttonTypeValue = button.cell?.valueForKey("buttonType")?.unsignedIntegerValue,
                    buttonType = NSButtonType(rawValue: buttonTypeValue)
                    else { return false }

                return buttonType == .SwitchButton
            })
            .first

        toggle?.hidden = true
        window.contentView?.display()
    }
}
```